# SMTP Relay Server with client authentication

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

i have a postfix STMP Relay Server using mandrillapp as my relay host, and for now my client (which use my SMTP Relay Server for sending mail) just sending email without authentication (just configuring mail account that will be forwarded by my SMTP Server). And now i'm wondering, can i implement some user authentication to my SMTP Server before sending mail from my client and log the user into maillog ?? If it's possible , what package and configuration that i need to do ?? thanks before ..